# Google Firebase performance monitoring : Ignore url pattern

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

When using Google Firebase network performance monitoring in Android, is there a way to ignore an url pattern (don't monitor it) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to particularly disable network monitoring for a particular pattern of URLs. Firebase Performance provides the option of [disabling automatic monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk?platform=android#disable-gradle-plugin) all network requests.

One [alternate way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/https_traces?platform=android#custom-url-patterns) to monitoring only the patterns you want to measure is by using custom HTTP requests monitoring.